# What are the minimum hard constraints that cause the nurse scheduling problem to be NP-complete?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

A client wishes to simplify the nurse scheduling problem to 'bypass' the NP-complete nature of this problem.

He is hoping to do so by **removing the requirement that there are any constraints for any of the nurses in terms of availability**.  (Also, assume there is only one shift type.)

Specifically:

- Given no minimum shift requirement for any nurse (0 hours is fine)
- Given complete availability of every nurse for every shift
- Given uniform shift lengths (but shifts CAN overlap)

... is the problem still NP-complete?

If not, then presumably it becomes NP-complete by adding one or more of the following constraints:

- There are a MAXIMUM number of shifts per nurse
- The shift lengths can vary

... are one and/or the other of the above sufficient for the problem to become NP-complete?  Or does the following constraint need to be added:

- Nurses have certain shifts they cannot work (i.e., complete availability of every nurse for every shift no longer applies)

With *all* of the above constraints in place, I am fairly confident that the conditions are satisfied for the problem to be NP-complete (but I would appreciate confirmation even of that!).

What are the **minimum** hard constraints for the nurse scheduling problem to be NP-complete?

Comment: Chek your terms properly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness : I think you mean NP-Complete. It seems a Integer Linear Programming task to me, making it NP complete, where regular Linear Programming can be polynomial.

Comment: @Pieter21: I am not too concerned about whether the constraint is just NP-Complete, or also NP-Hard - really, I'd like to know which constraints cause the problem to be either NP-Complete or NP-Hard.  Thanks!

Comment: I changed the question to refer to NP-complete, rather than NP-hard.